# Is there a pattern for managing (possibly multiple) requests for asynchronously-loaded data items?

Tags: design-patterns, asynchronous, silverlight-5.0

I have objects in a repository.  A managing class in the client requests object loads asynchronously on behalf of various modules.  The modules might all request a particular object (the same object) at the same time.  Is there a pattern for how to design this such that the managing class doesn't submit a request for each module request?

What I'm looking to do is have the managing class fire off one request to the web service when the first attempt to access the data comes in, and then fulfil all subsequent requests when the data arrives.

**Edit**

The modules don't know about each other or each others' requests.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways I've done this in the past.  But nothing "automated".

First:

Each asynchronous callback issues a call to the next object (if needed) and it cascades that way.  If a call fails, it stops the cascade at that point and only one error is shown.  The downside to this and the next one is the chattiness of the calls.

Second:

All asynchronous calls are made and a counter is set with expected returned items.  Each handler locks and updates the counter.  When counter==expectedCount then all items are returned.  A listbox displays the collection of items returned.  The downside to this is that you make all the calls without knowing if a) it is needed and b) if any failures should have stopped the process (and thus the calls).  It is also chatty and errors means unnecessary calls made.

Third:

The dumbest process only works if you have the rules well defined at the server.  You make an asynchronous call and the service does the cascade.  This only works best if all subsequent queries are returning children of the first query.  Then the results can be returned as a single object.  This definitely is NOT chatty.  The downside to this is the size of the returned object(s).

Comment: Ah. Your responses cover loading many items in one view (say). I'm talking about loading one item for many modules (say, a piece of shared configuration).